# How to Auto-TimeStamp as long as another column is NULL?

Tags: sql-server

I am creating the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AD_Group_Members]
(
    [AD_GROUP] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [MEMBER_ID] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [MEMBER_NAME] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [ADDED] [datetime] NULL,
    [REMOVED] [datetime] NULL,
    [CHECKED] DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT(GETDATE()), --Checking to see if Removed is NULL, then it is a valid record.

    CONSTRAINT [PK_AD_Group_Members] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([MEMBER_ID] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Per the comment, is it possible to make the CHECKED column timestamp so long REMOVED column is NULL?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're after. Do you want the contents of `CHECKED` to change depending on what's in `REMOVED`? If so, in what way? You could be looking for a computed column (possibly a new one) or an insert/update trigger. Or do you want to somehow query for something instead?

Comment: @JeroenMostert yes that is correct. I want the contents of CHECKED to be TIMESTAMPED regularly so long as REMOVED is NULL for the particular row. if a row has REMOVED as NOT NULL, the CHECKED should not update (Timestamped anymore)

Comment: @JeroenMostert yep, so as you said, in that case, CHECKED should keep the value it last had when REMOVED was NULL. If REMOVED becomes NULL again, then CHECKED should start updating once again

Comment: Nope - that won't happen based on constraints or anything else you can define at the table level. Code must be run to update the value whenever the row is actually "checked"  (or perhaps periodically - not clear what your requirement is). But this sounds like a big [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @SMor ya i guess ill have to code it. i hoped there would be something in SQL to do this instead but ill just script it out